# How to select some elements and append a div after them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've bene bursting my head for the last few hours. Here's the situation:

I have a website that has many divs, but many of them share classes (they are equal) but have some different texts. Example:

```
<div class="summary-title">
                <a href="/xaxaxaxa" class="summary-title-link">I Am That Girl</a></div>

<div class="summary-title">
                <a href="/whatverl" class="summary-title-link">I Am That Girl</a></div>
```

What I want to do is select each one of these divs and add a span whenever another div is hovered.

I mean, this is what I want to do: hover a div that's before the sumary-title div, a span with a class is appended inside the sumary-title div or out of it, whatever works.

That's what I got so far:

```
  $('summary-title').each(function(index) { 
    var content = $(index).next().text();
    $(index).append("<span class='hover-text'>"+content+"</span>");
  });
```

But I get an error that $ is not defined, probably because it is a closure?
I have no idea what to do. The code seems horrible too — i need to do this quickly and I just can't do. Would anyone help me at least know what to do?

Thanks

Comment: do you have jquery included in your page?

Comment: you are including the jquery script, right?

Comment: A closure would have nothing to do with it. As others have said, if you are getting this error, it means that you have not properly reference jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of making sure you have jQuery on your page and properly referring it,  your code should go like:

```
$('.summary-title').each(function() { 
    var content = $(this).children('a:first').text();
    $(this).append("<span class='hover-text'>"+content+"</span>");
});
```

Notice:

1. dot in class selector - `$('.summary-title')`
2. `this` instead of index - `$(this)`
3. `children` selector instead of `next`

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/au58c61r/).

To append this to a preceding element on hover use:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.summary-title').hover( function() {
        var content = $(this).children('a:first').text();
        $(this).prev().append("<span class='hover-text'>"+content+"</span>");
    });
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I was thinking, is there anyway to append this div to another div that's before each `.summary-title` and only when the user is hovering it?   

I think I got why next wasn't working. Thank you very much sir

Comment: Yes. Check the updated answer. But it will append on every hover event.

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is already an **implicit iteration** ( that loops through the set of elements in the jQuery collection.) and it's unnecessary to call `.each()` .

```
$('.summary-title').append(function() {
  return "<span class='hover-text'>" + $('a', this).text() + "</span>";
});
```